# How to get multiple entries of similar pattern from the same input line using grok pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I'm aware of grok pattern and able to parse and store the data into elastic search using logstash configuration file with filter and grok patterns.

For example:
If the data input line is:

```
Start-field1|field2|field3
```

then
field1, field2, field3 are being parsed and getting stored into elastic search successfully without any problem.

But now I have a input line like below:

```
Start-field1|field2|field3#Start-field1|field2|field3#Start-field1|field2|field3
```

means there are multiple occurrences of required pattern in the same input line, with **Start** as starting of pattern and **#** among all the required patterns.

Is there any way to fetch all such fields and store into elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?:case1|case2)` for as much occurrences you want. In each case you can put the same pattern like this: `(?:|Start-your_pattern) (?:|Start-your_pattern) (?:|Start-your_pattern)`
Also use the same field name multiple times. In this way you can store fields with all of their values. This is done by using `%{DATA:field1}, %{DATA:field2} and %{DATA:field3}` multiple times.

For this example:

```
Start - John 5 apples # Start - Joe 10 beers # Start - Max 2 eggs
```

Use this pattern:

```
Start - %{DATA:field1} %{DATA:field2} %{DATA:field3} (?:|# Start - %{DATA:field1} %{DATA:field2} %{DATA:field3}) (?:|# Start - %{DATA:field1} %{DATA:field2} %{DATA:field3})
```

You get this output:

```
{
  "field1": [
    [
      "John",
      "Joe",
      "Max"
    ]
  ],
  "field2": [
    [
      "5",
      "10",
      "2"
    ]
  ],
  "field3": [
    [
      "apples",
      "beers",
      "eggs"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Try it on http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer helped me a little, but I don't know how many times it occurs in that line. It can be any number of times(even 1 or 10 or 100, all are separated by # in between). Could you please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: When I've asked the same question in Elastic forum, they suggested to use mutate + split along with grok. But I'm not sure how to do it. Please help me on this. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-multiple-entries-of-similar-pattern-from-the-same-input-line-using-grok-pattern/245208/2

Comment: For example: This is what the data looks like and the grok pattern I have: Detailed_Dashboard-111|fileName|filePath|tableName|userName|ClassName|MethodName|server|04-08-2020 05:43:14.303 PM|04-08-2020 05:43:16.308 PM|350|false  Detailed_Dashboard\-%{USERNAME:ThreadId}\|%{WORD:FileName}\|%{DATA:FilePath}\|%{DATA:TableName}\|%{DATA:User}\|%{DATA:Class}\|%{DATA:Method}\|%{DATA:Server}\|%{DATA:FromTime}\|%{DATA:ToTime}\|%{NUMBER:ResponseTime:int}\|%{WORD:IsError}